# Moving fullscreen window from primary to secondary monitor causes visual artifact on primary monitor

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to move a fullscreen window from the primary monitor to the secondary monitor. However, while the window appears as it should on the secondary monitor, it also still appears on the primary monitor. This is just a visual artifact as clicking the 'window' on the primary monitor causes the program to minimize just like clicking outside of a program normally would.

After maximizing the program the function works as intended and is able to move the program between the two monitors problem free.

What is causing this visual artifact and more importantly, how can it be fixed?

This is the code I am using, mostly found through trial and error by looking at what decreases the visual artifacts and what doesn't.

```
void MoveFullscreenWindowToMonitor(HWND hwnd, HMONITOR fromMonitor, HMONITOR hMonitor) {
    MONITORINFO monitorInfo = { sizeof(MONITORINFO) };
    if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monitorInfo)) {
        RECT monitorRect = monitorInfo.rcMonitor;
        int width = monitorRect.right - monitorRect.left;
        int height = monitorRect.bottom - monitorRect.top;

        // Get the current window style
        LONG style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

        // Temporarily remove the WS_POPUP style to exit fullscreen mode
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_POPUP);

        // Move the window off the screen before moving it to the new monitor
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, -width, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        // Move the window to the new monitor and resize it to fit the monitor
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, monitorRect.left, monitorRect.top, width, height, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

        // Add the WS_POPUP style back to enter fullscreen mode
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style);

        // Move the window to the new monitor to fix the visual artifact
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, monitorRect.left, monitorRect.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        // Create a window that spans the entire work area of the original monitor
        //This part fixes another weird visual artifact on the target monitor
        MONITORINFOEX mi;
        mi.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
        GetMonitorInfo(fromMonitor, &mi);
        RECT rect = mi.rcWork;
        HWND extrahwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // Force a screen refresh on the original monitor
        UpdateWindow(extrahwnd);

        // Destroy the window
        DestroyWindow(extrahwnd);

        // Restore the window and move it to the new monitor to fix the visual artifact
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, monitorRect.left, monitorRect.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        // Give the window focus
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

        // Invalidate the window to force a redraw on the original monitor
        RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Everything works perfectly fine if I minimize and then maximize the application before running the code.

Comment: What's this whole `extrahwnd` business about? It doesn't appear to do anything meaningful, and the comment should probably read: *"This masks an issues that I don't care enough to solve"*. Maybe you should?

Comment: If I do not include that part of the code, there is another visual issue on the second monitor. This visual issue is solved when I create that window, force a refresh on it and delete it again. Honestly, I do not know why.

Comment: If you don't know why your code works, it doesn't.

Comment: You are probably right... Here's what it looks like without the code. Any idea what may be causing it? My window should be 100% black. This is on the second monitor.

https://imgur.com/a/uwSnKhr

Comment: Calling `MoveWindow` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) with new bounds and `SwitchToThisWindow` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-switchtothiswindow) should be enough.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried this approach but it doesn't seem to work.
`MoveWindow(hwnd, monitorRect.left, monitorRect.top, width, height, FALSE);`
And then
`SwitchToThisWindow(hwnd, FALSE);`
This does not solve the problem

EDIT: If I minimize the program and maximize it and then proceed to run this code it works.

Comment: It works fine for me, but it ultimately depends on the window/app in question. Please provide a fully reproducible sample with a target window https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example